# Recursive method returns a string in reverse order needs String and Index position as parameters

Tags: java

I am attempting to use recursion to reverse a string but the special twist is that I must start at a specified index return that character contained at the index and then reverse the remaining string after that index and combine the two into one output. I have tried to do this and sometimes it gives an array out of bounds exception and sometimes ends up with more letters than it should have such as this test of helloooo coming out as lloooooo. Any help with tweaking this code would be appreciated as I became really lost when the need for the second parameter was known to me.

```
  public class ReverseTest
    {
        public static void main(String[] argv) 
        {
            System.out.println(reverse("a", 0));
            System.out.println(reverse("hi", 0));
            System.out.println(reverse("helloooo", 2));
        }


        public final static String reverse(String s, int ind)
        {
            int length = s.length(); //get string length

            if (length <= 1) //if length is 1 or lower just repeat the string nothing to do
                return s; //return string
            else //if we have something to work with...
                return s.substring(ind) + reverse(s.substring(ind + 1, length - 1), ind); //return substring of necessary index + reverse the rest and display in one string
        }
    }
```

Comment: For clarity sake would reverse("Hello", 1), become "Heoll" or "oellH"?

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and expected output?

Comment: Some example output would be if I inputted Hello with an index of 1 I would output e (the char with 1 index) and oll the reversed rest of string and then put together eoll

Comment: @user1524882: Then see my answer. I think I've cracked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong with your version, but I built my own according to what I find to be an intuitive implementation:

```
private static String reversePartially(String initial, int target) {
    return reversePartially(initial, target, target);
}

private static String reversePartially(String initial, int index, int target) {
    // if we are at the target index put the character at the front
    if(index == target) return initial.charAt(target) + reversePartially(initial, index + 1, target);
    // if we are in the second part return the characters reversed
    if(index > target) return reversePartially(initial, index + 1, target) + initial.charAt(index);
    // base condition
    if(index == initial.length()) return "";
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks this works here I won't use this exact implementation because of course it is yours but I will use it to dissect the steps I need and see how can I fix my method. Cheers mate

Comment: Why even bother with the first conditional? Just call reversePartially(initial, target, target);

Answer (score 0):

Since this might be HW, heres a hint. I think you're confusing two parts of the problem

1. Reverse the substring from index i to end
2. Append the substring from 0 to i-1 to the reversal of i to end

Try breaking those two up in to a function that looks like

```
String reverse(String s);
String reversePart(String s, index i);
```

where the second function will call the first.  You can write a recursive function for reversing a string without using an index parameter.

Comment: Yeah this seems like what I should be doing split it up into two parts of getting the index character and then appending it to the index+1 to end reversed string. Thanks I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual solution to the above problem.. This Code Is Tested.. All The Best.. Regards : Amit Sinha.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class RevString
{
    public String reverse(String s, int index )
        {
            if( index>0 )
            {
                return s.charAt( --index) + reverse( s, index);
            }
            return "";
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
        {
            DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
            String a;// the given string
            System.out.println("Enter a String");
            a=in.readLine();
            RevString obj=new RevString();
            int l=a.length();  // calculates Length of String
            System.out.println(obj.reverse(a,l));  // Pass Parameter as String, Length.
        }
}
```